# how to adjust the derailer - apart from the L/H limiting screws

Tags: derailleur, gears, front

Pardon my newb terminology. My bike's chain will not stay on the H gear (the big ring) The front derailleur will not allow it.

[image: fully loosened - wont go higher]

I have loosened the limiter screw out to it's maximum and, still, no dice. Clearly there is more room to move, as I demonstrate manually:

[image: see!]

I want to know what to attempt to adjust next. Clearly there is a bias toward the Low cog. Ideally I'd want to tighten that limiting screw so I'd have more room to manouvre in future.

Which of the other hinges should I try to work with next?

[image]

Every video I've found online so far only deals with those limiting screws.

Comment: There are basically 5 adjustments:  Derailer height on seat tube.  Derailer twist on seat tube.  Low limit.  High limit.  Cable length/taughtness.  Cable length/taughtness is adjusted two ways -- loosening the cable clamp and sliding the cable in or out, and using the barrel adjuster.  Generally screw the barrel adjuster almost all the way in, then clamp the cable, then use the barrel for fine adjustment/stretch.

Comment: A 3x shifter is trickier, of course, since the cable length needs to be fine-tuned to hit the center sprocket.

Comment: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustments is a good starting point for the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loosen the screw that holds the cable and pull that cable out a little bit.

The limiter screws that you've used so far are rather used to prevent the chain from falling off, and it's a finer tuning than you appear to need now. Thus it would be useful to level them out before pulling the cable. After you adjust the cable, take a few minutes to make sure the derailleur does not throw the chain over the outer gear.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that made a difference for sure. I pulled it pretty tight and I can get up there as long as the back derailer doesn't go to its highest gear. I should tighten it a bit more but, perhaps, I need to change the gear cables. It's my girlfirend's bike and I'm pretty sure she hasn't had new cables in a year or so, and she cycles alot.

Comment: Gear cables should last longer than a year. My first adult bike had over 12000 km on it before I retired it, never once needed to change gear cables, and I rode it in all kinds of weather. Might be more needed on a mountain bike that gets a lot of dirt on it, but you should get quite a bit of mileage out of them.

Comment: Depends on the weather and type of shifter you run. I find trigger shifters are a lot less friendly to shift cables than gripshifts (which I hate) or my downtube friction shifters.